# ¿Cómo creo un ciclo loop (ensamblador) en mi programa C?

Tags: c, ensamblador

necesito hacer un programa en C con lenguaje ensamblador embebido y necesito hacer un ciclo loop, realmente no entiendo la sintaxis, si pudieran explicarme con un ejemplo sencillo (imprimir un numero del 0 a 10) se los agradecería.

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: que buscaste, viste, averiguaste hasta ahora?

Comment: `10` *start*. `20` *run*. `30` *goto 10*.

Answer (score 1):

gbianchi encontré esto, es para C++ pero más o menos me estoy guiando: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o una edición a la pregunta?

Comment: Una edición a la pregunta